# Stickytable not working for tables in boostrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, sticky, tableheader

I am trying to use sticky table header js to fix the table headers. I worked on all other table, but not working on tables in boostrap modal.

```
$("#measurementAndQuestionPage").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $("#tblVitalCalendarViewForMeasurement").stickyTableHeaders();
});
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Could you post some code?

Comment: My code:   $("#measurementAndQuestionPage").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
         $("#tblVitalCalendarViewForMeasurement").stickyTableHeaders();
        });

Answer (score 0):

I thinks these links will help you

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html

Comment: I am using boostrap modal not magnific popup